# How to to startup oracle report server using startComponent.cmd when access to domain is denied

Tags: oracle, report, weblogic, wlst, reportserver

Can someone help me figure out the how to properly startup oracle report server? `AdminServer, OHS, WLS_FORMS and WLS_REPORTS` are up and running. When I try to startup oracle reports server using `WLST` command it says:

```
`Connecting to Node Manager ...`

<Jan 27, 2020 3:59:42 PM SGT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.>
<Jan 27, 2020 3:59:42 PM SGT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to HMACDRBG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.>
<Jan 27, 2020 3:59:43 PM SGT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090909> <Using the configured custom SSL Hostname Verifier implementation: weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier$NullHostnameVerifier.>
This Exception occurred at Mon Jan 27 15:59:45 SGT 2020.
weblogic.nodemanager.NMException: Received error message from Node Manager Server: [Access to domain 'base_domain' for user 'eXq1WrTnqX' denied]. Please check Node Manager log for details.
Error: Error occurred while performing nmConnect : Cannot connect to Node Manager. : Received error message from Node Manager Server: [Access to domain 'base_domain' for user 'eXq1WrTnqX' denied]. Please check Node Manager log for details. 
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
```

I tried connecting in WLST using `connect('username','<password>','localhost:7001')` and I can connect but when I try it in CMD "`Oracle_Home\userproject\domain\base_domain\bin\startComponent.cmd MyServer1`" using the same username and password it says it cannot connect.

I tried changing the hashed username and password in `nm_properties` to plain text but I got an error so I have to change it back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Try as root or give permissions like:

- chmod +x *.sh